# DB2 tablescan using join between primary key

Tags: indexing, db2, primary-key

in a db2 database i'm running this query:

```
select * from mytable t1 left join mytable t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

where "id" is the only "primary key" in "mytable"

the explain show a tablescan:

```
RETURN  
 MSJOIN 
  TBSCAN    
   SORT     
    mytable  TBSCAN 
  FILTER    
   TBSCAN   
   SORT     
    mytable  TBSCAN
```

if i do the same query in othertable i obtain what i'm expecting: the use of the primary key (pk):

```
RETURN
MSJOIN
 othertable  FETCH 
  PK_othertable  IXSCAN
 FILTER
  othertable  FETCH 
  PK_othertable  IXSCAN
```

why in one case db2 during the join don't use the pk and in other use the pk like i expect?

Comment: You are reading the entire table, not just a few selected rows. Are you sure you want to do this? What's the use case?

Comment: my problem is about the tablescan in the explain instead using the existing primary key.
i don't understand why db2 do this

Comment: @StefanoTinarelli because it is faster to do a full tablescan then using index

Answer (score 0):

Db2 uses cost-based optimizer.
It probably decides, that TBSCANs are cheaper for certain queries.
You may try to get desired access plan with the corresponding hint (it's called optimization guidelines in Db2) like below:

```
select * from mytable t1 
left join mytable t2 on t1.id = t2.id
/*
<OPTGUIDELINES>
...
</OPTGUIDELINES>
*/
;
```

where optimization guidelines may look like:

(let Db2 choose some JOIN request like MSJOIN, NLJOIN, etc. using IXSCAN with particular index name):

```
<OPTGUIDELINES>
  <JOIN>
    <IXSCAN TABLE="T1" INDEX="UNQUALIFIED_PK_INDEX_NAME"/>
    <IXSCAN TABLE="T2" INDEX="UNQUALIFIED_PK_INDEX_NAME"/>
  </JOIN>
</OPTGUIDELINES>
```

(NLJOIN with IXSCANs using whatever appropriate indexes):

```
<OPTGUIDELINES>
  <NLJOIN>
    <IXSCAN TABLE="T1"/>
    <IXSCAN TABLE="T2"/>
  </NLJOIN>
</OPTGUIDELINES>
```

Or use whatever else acceptable guidelines to get the access plan desired.
Refer to the [Optimization profiles and guidelines](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=plans-optimization-profiles-guidelines) topic for more details.

Compare the total cost of each access plan to understand, why Db2 prefers some particular access plan (likely with the smallest total cost).